# Angular 4 event binding for two events

Tags: javascript, angular

Angular 4 event bindings typically look like

`<button id="actionButton" (touchend)="action.click()">{{action.label}}</button>`

However, with jQuery I can do and effectively bind an action to two seperate events if needed, like so

`$("#actionButton").on("mouseup touchend", function() {`

Is there any way in Angualar 4 to bind the same function to two seperate events? Or do I need to define the other event and function seperately like this

`<button id="actionButton" (touchend)="action.click()" (mouseup)="action.click()">{{action.label}}</button>`

Comment: Would not it be better to create an angular directive for that and there using the api hostlistener to listen for specific events? You  can define your logic there in that directive.

Comment: https://medium.com/@TheLarkInn/hacking-angular2-binding-multiple-dom-events-f781b14ef676#.1v9ydrcb0

Comment: One way would be: If you manually do addEventListener  in onInit and RemoveEventListener in onDestroy. Then have both call click handler. clickhander =( () => {this. //enable this}).bind(this); ||| addEventListener('click',this.clickhandler)) and removeEventListener('click',this.clickhandler))

Comment: Did you try to search?https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6675

Comment: @yurzui only the angular documentation and github, thought it was a fringe case after seeing no results decided to ask here if anyone had a relable solution, which you provided with the medium article, thanks